# Query error, invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write aquery based on the old Northwind database. My task is to write a query, that will give me "number of units in stock by category and supplier continent". I've wrote something like this:

```
    SELECT  Categories.CategoryName as "Categories",
        CASE WHEN Suppliers.Country in 
        ('UK','Spain','Sweden','Germany','Norway',
                  'Denmark','Netherlands','Finland','Italy','France')
            THEN 'Europe'
            WHEN Suppliers.Country in
             ('USA', 'Brazil','Canada')
            THEN 'America'
            ELSE 'Asia-Pacific' 
            END AS "Supplier Continent", 
        sum(Products.UnitsInStock) as "Units In Stock"
FROM Suppliers
INNER JOIN Products ON Products.SupplierID=Suppliers.SupplierID
INNER JOIN Categories ON Categories.CategoryID= Products.CategoryID
GROUP BY Categories.CategoryName;
```

Sadly the MS SQL Server Management Studio throws me an error :

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 165
>
> Column 'Suppliers.Country' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What should I change to fix this error and make my query work?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? It's quite clear, in my view. `Suppliers.Country` isn't being aggregated, neither is it in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: just include Suppliers.Country in group by clause. `GROUP BY Categories.CategoryName, Suppliers.Country;`

Comment: @iSR5 I wouldn't recommend that, I doubt it'll give the Op what they're after.

Comment: @Larnu yes, but it'll be a way to understand what was the issue and how to fix it. So, after that, he'll know what to do next ;) . .

Comment: @ISR5 It works, but the result is different, I've received 45 rows instead of 21 (number of categories)

Comment: @DoktorAgon as of my replay to Larnu, I gave you the fix to know what was the issue, so, now you know the issue is not including that column, and you need to alter your query to avoid that column (maybe using subquery will solve that) .

Comment: @iSR5 Right, I wil ldo that, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your original query up in a derived table. Aggregate its result:

```
select "Categories", "Supplier Continent", sum("UnitsInStock") as "Units In Stock"
from
(
    SELECT  Categories.CategoryName as "Categories",
            CASE WHEN Suppliers.Country in 
            ('UK','Spain','Sweden','Germany','Norway',
                      'Denmark','Netherlands','Finland','Italy','France')
                THEN 'Europe'
                WHEN Suppliers.Country in
                 ('USA', 'Brazil','Canada')
                THEN 'America'
                ELSE 'Asia-Pacific' 
                END AS "Supplier Continent", 
            Products.UnitsInStock as "UnitsInStock" 
    FROM Suppliers
    INNER JOIN Products ON Products.SupplierID=Suppliers.SupplierID
    INNER JOIN Categories ON Categories.CategoryID= Products.CategoryID
) dt
GROUP BY "Categories", "Supplier Continent";
```

Comment: Code is different, but result is correct. Thank you!